# (output format) Unexpected end of file - token expected in python function

Tags: python

```
import string
l=(string.ascii_lowercase)
m=input().lower()
n=input().lower()

def check(l,m,n):    
    for i in range(len(m)):
        if m[i]==n[i]:
            continue
        elif l.index(n[i])>l.index(m[i]):
            return(-1)
        elif l.index(n[i])<l.index(m[i]):
            return(1)
    return(0)    

check(l,m,n)
```

so the output for the above code should be 0,1 or -1 I do get that when using external IDE but I got this when submitting to an online judge

```
Checker Log

wrong output format Unexpected end of file - token expected
```

is it something to do with return

Comment: Hi, try to be more precise. Say what the code has to do, not only the final output.

Comment: The online judge might be expecting the output in other formats for example string or list. Check what format it is expecting.

Comment: @mad_ it's 'int'

Comment: @A.Wolf it compares the two strings in lexicographical order

Comment: P s it was accepted when I used "print(**no**) and return" in the place of "return(**no**)"

Comment: my guess is when returning some value python add  eof statement to show it's over but when using just return it does nothing

Comment: I execute your code and it works fine. Try to debug it and post the entire error; try to understand in which line it breaks. As I said, I tried both with single character and strings and it works as expected.

Comment: I do know it's works but when I return values directly there's some extra stuff at the end